# Can I loop through directories and subdirectories and store certain files in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I have one folder that contains many subfolders, and images within those subfolders. I have code that loops through the folders and subfolders and prints out the name of each image one at a time. I want all of these image names to be stored in a single array. How do I get my loop to append each image name to the same array?

I have only seen similar solutions on Linux or Matlab so far, but not on python.

```py
files = []
#r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for face_image in f :
        if face_image.endswith("g"): #to get all '.jpg' and all '.png' files
            print(face_image)
```

When I run the loop above, I get all ~1000 image names printed. But when I then try and print(face_image) outside of the loop, only the name of the final image in the loop is printed. I now now this is because I have not appended each name to an array, but am not sure how to go about this? Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your print statement, you can use `files.append(face_image)` to add the face image to your list. When the loops are done, all valid image names will be in the list for you to use.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! When I do print(face_image) within the loop, the output I want is produced. when I then exit the loop and do print(face_image), only the last file is produced. The same as before

Comment: @charlotte Do `print(files)` instead. The variable `files` is what's actually holding the list; `face_image` will only ever hold one name at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Using pathlib and a recursive glob pattern:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_types = ("jpg", "png")
file_paths = []
for file_type in file_types:
    file_paths.extend(Path(".").glob(f"**/*.{file_type}"))

file_names = [file_path.name for file_path in file_paths]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if this was a legit question or not.  You need to append the files to the list.

```
files = []
#r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for face_image in f :
        if face_image.endswith("g"): #to get all '.jpg' and all '.png' files
            print(face_image)
            files.append(face_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    # collect all images
    files += [os.path.join(r, file) for file in f]
    # filter images
    files = [ff for ff in files if ff.endswith('g')]
```

or a little more compact:

```
files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    # collect all images that end with 'g'
    files += [os.path.join(r, file) for file in f if file.endswith('g')]
```

Comment: It didn't like the last line of code unfortunately. "AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'endswith'"

Comment: you probably have a typo, file is not a generator, but an element being iterated over (second snippet) and same comment for f in first snippet. I would double check you match mine exactly. Both of my code snippets work on my box.

Comment: I changed `files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('g')]` to `files = [ff for ff in files if ff.endswith('g')]` to be more clear.